# Does TestNG skip test when too many are failing?

Tags: testng

I see skip TestNG skip tests when running everything. But, when running one by one it works. My tests are not dependent to each other. Any ideas?

Comment: There's many reasons TestNG might skip a test; without seeing your configuration and test definitions, along with some sample output, your question is difficult to answer.  Care to share?

Answer (score 0):

No, TestNG shouldn't skip test when too many are failing.

But it will be helpful to share the tests and the testng results to have a better look into the problem.